Together we stand... I mean...,
What's shown below? Explain your reasoning.



Should the word tag be here?

@PDT No, no word-tag

Edited the puzzle with some necessary info. Now I think it's more complete.

znlor s=sebag, f=fvqr naq gur inyhr vf gur cbfvgvba jvguva gur tebhc

@BeastlyGerbil I'm not saying you're wrong, but if that's correct I don't understand why the bottom square would be bigger. I was looking for ways to (rot13) ynory gur fvqrf bs gur fdhnerf jvgu yrggref bs gur nycunorg, jvgu 4 fvqrf bs 6 fdhnerf lbh pna ynory 24 yrggref (fb pbzovar v/w naq h/i). Gurer ner n pbhcyr bs ybtvpny jnlf gb qb gung, gung raq hc jvgu f naq s va gubfr cynprf, ohg abar bs gurz erfhyg va nalguvat hfrshy jura lbh genpr gur erq yvar.

Read all the comments. Actually nothing to do with a dice. @Vicky is close, just need to figure out what S and F stand for.

@Prim3numbah fgneg naq svavfu znlor? Uzz, ynoryyvat gur fvqrf jvgu 4 yrggref va gung beqre, ntnva va gur "boivbhf" jnl (fgnegvat jvgu NOPQ ba gur ynetr fdhner) nyfb qbrfa'g fcryy bhg nalguvat boivbhf.

@Vicky That's right (S and F I mean). Don't want to say too much but keep trying and see if you can make it fit somehow

@Vicky: Oh, that interpretation of S and F is good. By the way rot13(lbh qba'g unir gb pbzovar yrggref – lbh pna znc gur jubyr nycunorg vs lbh hfr gur gjb "svfu-gnvy" rqtrf, gbb),

Yup, @MOehm is right

Thanks to the hint from @MOehm I've finally figured it out.

 Label the sides of the squares (and the "fish tail" ends) with letters of the alphabet, starting at the larger bottom square on the left side (labelled "S" for "Start") and then following the lines up and right along the top side of the "fish", and back down the other side to the bottom of the first large square again.
 
          1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 Lefts    A C E G I K M
 Tops     B D F H J L
 Rights   Y W U S Q O
 Bottoms  Z X V T R P N
 

The red line then spells out

 
 4R   S
 4T   H
 6R   O
 1L   A
 6T   L
 6R   O
 3T   F
 3T   F
 5L   I
 4R   S
 4T   H
 


 SHOAL OF FISH, which is exactly what the picture looks like!


Nice :) And the title ofc just meant they're not standing but... and the "below" was hinting "under..."
